# Sharing System Clipboard with vim under cygwin

Tags: cygwin, vim

I built a pretty good cygwin setup under Windows7. I installed vim under cygwin. Now, I can't share the system clipboard with vim. `vim --version` gives:

```
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

I tried setting `set clipboard+=unnamed` inside my .vimrc but it was no use. I tried `P`, `"+p`, `*p` and `"*p` but none of these pasted from the system clipboard. However, pressing SHIFT+Ins on cygwin prompt pastes from system clipboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the plugin [fakeclip](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip).  This will enable the system clipboard behaviour to work in cygwin.

Comment: tried. no help. tried this one as well http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_Windows_clipboard_in_Cygwin_Vim no dice. :-(

Answer (score 5):

Copy text from vim under cygwin, just press `"`key `+`key `y`key in visual mode :

> "+y

Paste text to vim under cygwin, just press `"` key `+`key `p`key in normal mode :

> "+p

Comment: Where can I find references on this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Cygwin uses `/dev/clipboard` to access windows clipboard. For copying in visual mode, you can just do something like:

```
:'<,'>w !cat > /dev/clipboard
```

In order to paste from a windows clipboard, you can do something like this:

```
:r !cat /dev/clipboard
```

I have been using this method for some time now without any issues. But it only works for console version of vim. Gvim for windows has + register which allows you to copy and paste from windows clipboard. So, it's as easy as "+y (copy) and "+p (paste).

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_Windows_clipboard_in_Cygwin_Vim